# Get time left until sunday 9:30 pm

Tags: c#, datetime

What I want to do is basically in the question title.

This is what I've tried so far, unsuccessfully.

Note that I haven't implemented exact hour and minute yet (9:30 pm).

It actually seems to always return a value between 00:00:59 and 00:00:01 for some reason

```
DateTime nextSunday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(((int)DayOfWeek.Sunday - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7) + new TimeSpan(21, 30, 0);
TimeSpan untilNextSunday = nextSunday - DateTime.Now;

await ReplyAsync($"It is in **{TimeSpan.FromSeconds(untilNextSunday.Seconds)}**");
```

Which equals to

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var daysUntilSunday = ((int)DayOfWeek.Sunday - (int)today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7;
var nextSunday = today.AddDays(daysUntilSunday);
var ts = new TimeSpan(21, 30, 0);
nextSunday = nextSunday.Date + ts;

TimeSpan untilNextSunday = nextSunday - DateTime.Now;
```

If possible, I'd also like to use Paris TimeZone.

Comment: `TimeSpan.Seconds` only returns the seconds component of the total time-span. Perhaps you should use `TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`?

Comment: Looks better, thanks. It now returns ``08:51:02.3230000`` tho.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(untilNextSunday.TotalSeconds)` is exactly the same as `untilNextSunday`.

Comment: Are you happy to use 3rd party libraries? I'd use my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library for this, which I'd expect to end up with more readable code. I'm happy to write up an answer that uses it, but that won't be very useful if you have to stick to `DateTime`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I'd like to see it. I've tried Noda Time a couple of times but struggle doing some basic things. This would be a good example.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Righto, will do :)

Comment: @Enigmativity: It's there now.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to find all of the `DateTime.Today.AddDays(((int)DayOfWeek.Sunday - (int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek + 7) % 7) + new TimeSpan(21, 30, 0)` arithmetic quite confusing. Instead I try to go with a more iterative approach that can be clearly reasoned about.

Try this:

```
public static DateTime GetNextDateTime(DateTime now, DayOfWeek targetDay, TimeSpan targetTime)
{
    DateTime target = now.Date.Add(targetTime);

    while (target < now || target.DayOfWeek != targetDay)
    {
        target = target.AddDays(1.0);
    }

    return target;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime target = GetNextDateTime(DateTime.Now, DayOfWeek.Sunday, new TimeSpan(21, 30, 0));
TimeSpan untilNextSunday = target.Subtract(now);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using Noda Time, including time zone handling. It doesn't attempt to handle "interesting" situations where (say) you ask for the next 1:30am, and it's already 1:45am but the clock goes back at 2am - in which case the right answer is really "45 minutes" but this code will give you a week instead.

```cs
using System;
using NodaTime;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var duration = GetDurationToNext(
            IsoDayOfWeek.Sunday, new LocalTime(21, 30),
            DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Paris"],
            SystemClock.Instance);

        Console.WriteLine($"Duration: {duration}");
    }

    static Duration GetDurationToNext(
        IsoDayOfWeek dayOfWeek,
        LocalTime timeOfDay,
        DateTimeZone zone,
        IClock clock) // Or just take an instant
    {
        var now = clock.GetCurrentInstant();
        var localNow = now.InZone(zone).LocalDateTime;

        var localNext = localNow
            .Date.With(DateAdjusters.NextOrSame(dayOfWeek))
            .At(timeOfDay);
        // Handle "we're already on the right day-of-week, but
        // later in the day"
        if (localNext <= localNow)
        {
            localNext = localNext.PlusWeeks(1);
        }

        var zonedNext = localNext.InZoneLeniently(zone);
        var instantNext = zonedNext.ToInstant();
        return instantNext - now;
    }
}
```